# Allow image to be centered and sized to fit button || CSS

Tags: css

I'm making a 'To-Do' list, and I'm trying to style the buttons to look like X marks to delete a bullet point. The image appears, but it's only a tiny little section of it. Is there any way for the image to be centered and sized down to fit inside the button?

```
input[type="button"] {
background: url(xmark.png);
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
border: none;
float: right;
margin: 3px;
cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;
 }
```

Comment: `background-position: center center;` or just add to background param, `background: url(xmark.png) center;`

Comment: `background-size: contain;` and `background-position: center center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-size: contain;` and `background-position: center center;`

Should do it.

---

In fact, `background-size: contain` may be good enough depending on the size of your box and image, but the position property makes things safe.

`background-size: contain;` scales the image to fit completely in the box (So your image won't get cut off), and `background-position: center center;` quite clearly centers the image horizontally and vertically.